# Transaction verification failed when using different type of states as input and output

Tags: corda

I am trying to create a corda transaction where I am consuming one type of input state while creating another type of state as output but while verification the input and the output state are being evaluated using the same command in different contracts hence the verification part is failing. Is there any way through which the input contract would be evaluated using the command for the first state while output state would be verified using another contract.

In both contracts I am doing something like this:

```
val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands>()
when (command.value) {
    is Commands.Issue -> verifyIssue(tx, setOfSigners)
    is Commands.Transfer -> verifyTransfer(tx, setOfSigners)
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised command")
}
```

This is the output in the log file:

```
[WARN ] 2018-01-31T12:07:53,963Z [Node thread] flow.[51120088-7c8c-457b-b143-966b85e788cb].run - Flow finished with exception
net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractRejection: Contract verification failed: Required com.template.AssetContract.Commands command, contract: com.template.AssetContract@53cc722e, transaction: 6FBE6CB29E2385C81683ED25C0A5CE21E07A18BE9DFD74AD47C45223138B35E6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write each contract so that it only imposes conditions on certain types of states. For example, suppose you have two state types - `XState` and `YState` - and two types of contract - `XContract` and `YContract`. Then could then write your contracts as follows:

```
class XContract : Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val inputXStates = tx.inputsOfType<XState>()
        val outputXStates = tx.outputsOfType<XState>()

        requireThat {
            "All XState inputs are unapproved." using (inputXStates.all { it.approved == false })
            "All XState outputs are approved" using (outputXStates.all { it.approved == true })
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
class YContract : Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val inputYStates = tx.inputsOfType<YState>()
        val outputYStates = tx.outputsOfType<YState>()

        requireThat {
            "All YState inputs are unaudited." using (inputYStates.all { it.audited == false })
            "All YState outputs are audited" using (outputYStates.all { it.audited == true })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @joel. I faced the similar kind of issue. But I am not sure what those amendments in the contract does. 
Can you please give the overview of the above amendments. Thank you

Comment: Look at the lines where I grab the states to check - for example, `tx.inputsOfType<YState>()`. I only check these states, the `YState`s. My contract doesn't opine on any other state types that may exist.