# Multiple states in same contract is failing at verify

Tags: corda

This is what I have implemented in my CordApp:
[image: CordApp]

Now while doing flow test, It's passing till Contract C. But the flow test for Contract D is failing. According to logs, **it's trying to validate all states(i.e i/p and o/p) using same Command.**

I found one similar question: [Transaction verification failed when using different type of states as input and output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541847/transaction-verification-failed-when-using-different-type-of-states-as-input-and)

But if that was true than my Contract C Flow test cases should have also failed?

Nevertheless, as mentioned in answer, I removed validation for input states in contract D, so that one contract will validate only one state. But still same error is coming.

Any pointer on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

- Contracts do not verify individual states, they verify entire transactions
- When verifying a transaction, the contracts of both the input and output states are run

So in your case, if I understand your diagram correctly:

- The first transaction (from the left) has no inputs, output `StateA`, and is verified by running `ContractA` (associated with `StateA`)
- The second transaction has no inputs, output `StateB`, and is verified by running `ContractB` (associated with `StateB`)
- The third transaction has input `StateB`, output `StateC`, and is verified by running `ContractB` (associated with `StateB`) and `ContractC` (associated with `StateC`)
- The fourth transaction (on the far-right) has inputs `StateA` and `StateC`, output `StateD`, and is verified by running `ContractA` (associated with `StateA`), `ContractC` (associated with `StateC`) and `ContractD` (associated with `StateD`)

Comment: you understood the diagram correctly, so what can be the possible problem then? I am inserting StateA and StateC directly in vault by `getServices().recordTransactions()`. And when I pass everything to TxBuilder and invoke verify, `contractA` is invoked and `StateD` and Command associated with D is passed and hence the error.

Comment: Yes, that's as expected, no? The last transaction will be verified by Contracts A, C and D.

Comment: Oh ok, please let me know if I understood correctly. My fourth transaction have three total state, and as those three transaction have three different contract. So, that's why my new 4th Txn will be passed to all three contracts with all 3 states with the new command defined in the Fourth Transaction?

Comment: Yep, exactly :)

Comment: Thanks Joel, just one last question, is this documented anywhere in Corda docs or any WP? Why such  behavior, why not just pass particular input transactions to particular contract? This is resulting in same Command name to be declared in all different contracts..

Comment: Yes - see https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-contracts.html#transaction-verification for example.

Comment: oh ok, this one, `A transaction is only valid if the contract of every input state and every output state considers it to be valid`. Thanks for the help :)